# java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to disable other buttons when one is selected

Tags: java, android, android-button

I have a problem with my code. I'm trying to disable all other buttons when one is selected. Are there any other options for disabling other buttons?

I wish it would highlight only one button at the same time.

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (flaga == 0) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.vga1:
                    try {
                        buttonVmute.setEnabled(true);
                        buttonStart.setEnabled(false);
                        ClientThread clientThread = new ClientThread("192.168.1.123");
                        new Thread(clientThread).start();
                        Thread.sleep(20);
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(soket.getOutputStream())), true);
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                        out.println("");
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                        out.println("bbbb");
                        Thread.interrupted();

                    } catch (UnknownHostException | NullPointerException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.hdmi1:
                    try {
                        buttonVmute.setEnabled(false);
                        buttonStart.setEnabled(true);
                        ClientThread clientThread = new ClientThread("192.168.1.124");
                        new Thread(clientThread).start();
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(soket.getOutputStream())), true);
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                        out.println("");
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                        out.println("nnnnnn");
                        Thread.interrupted();

                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Podłącz wifi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

There is a logcat:

```
04-21 14:36:37.038  20086-20086/com.example.mateusz.tabfragment W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: can you post the whole stacktrace? just the one line doesnt help that much.

Comment: And ideally, tidy up your source code to be a little more compact - those multiple line-breaks all over the place really don't help. (Your exception handling strategy needs a lot of work, too...)

Comment: I have this strange feeling that you are sending the UI thread to sleep, and even interrupting it. O_O

Answer (score 0):

Could you post all cod? I think the problem is with `buttonVmute and buttonStart`, they probably don't have value which identificate your layout buttons.

Try to make new instance of this variables and findView element in your Try{}.

```
try{    
buttonVmute = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.button_name);
buttonVmute.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Than see if it crash in same line, or your problem is solved.